# Error executing Java jar file : Could not find or load main class A

Tags: java, jar

I googled to see solution for my problem, but no luck. I need to run two classes using single java jar file. Below are the steps I performed:

```
> jar cvf db-p.jar A.class B.class 
added manifest
adding: A.class(in = 31907) (out= 14360)(deflated 54%) 
adding: B.class(in = 14066) (out= 6912)(deflated 50%) 
> java -classpath db-p.jar A
Error: Could not find or load main class A
```

Please let me know what's the issue with my steps.

Comment: Does your class A has a package name?

Comment: Yes, it has a package name

Comment: then you should be specifying full package name with A as part of command.

Comment: add that package name to the command: eg: `java -classpath db-p.jar some.name.here.A`